# Add link to materialize tab

Tags: tabs, materialize

I am using the materialize tab that is in the page [materialize tab](http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.1/layout03/user-profile-page.html)

My goal is to add a link in the menu that go to CreateAlbum tab.

I tried `href="#CreateAlbum"` but it didn't work. How can I do that?

if i link

```
<a href="{{path('homepage')}}#CreateAlbum">
```

or

```
<a href="#CreateAlbum">
```

don't work and don't reload page

Comment: Is it possible to post more code?

Comment: the html is the same of link page .. what code do you need??

Comment: If it is on the same page then your code `<a href="#CreateAlbum">` should work. Don't know how you are doing. It doesn't reload the page. If possible create a fiddle and we can look what's going wrong.

Comment: yes my problem is that no reload page if i 'm in homepage and so don't work